# What is Python Server-sent event return Format?

Tags: python, django, real-time

I have a django project using Server-Sent Events and redis pubsub system. 
The code is as follows:

I open the event by using JavaScript code

```javascript
var eventSource = new EventSource("/tweets/stream");

eventSource.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log(message) 
}, false);
```

Then in my python code, i process it by using redis subscribe. When i get new data and response to the request. There is no data display. So i think there is a problem in my response format.

```
def stream(request):
   def stream_data():
      REDIS_CONF = {
          'host': 'localhost',
          'port': 6379,
          'db': 1,
     }
     red = redis.StrictRedis(**REDIS_CONF)
     pubsub = red.pubsub()
     pubsub.subscribe('@NBA')
     for message in pubsub.listen():
        long_string = '''
        id: 123 \n\n
        data: 123123123 \n
        '''
        return long_string

    return HttpResponse(stream_data(), content_type="text/event-stream")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse
...
...
return StreamingHttpResponse(stream_data(), content_type="text/event-stream")
```

Using StreamingHttpResponse instead of HttpResponse will fixed this problem.